# Differential geometry; evaluating the differential $df$ of a function $f$ from the sphere to a meridian and the first fundamental form

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $C$ be the meridian $C= \{ (x,y,z) \in \Bbb S^2 | y=0,x\geq 0 \}$. Let $f$ map the sphere $\Bbb S^2$ to $C$ such that $f$ maps every point on the sphere to the unique point on $C$ with the same $z$-coordinate. Now I need to show that $f$ is continuous at all points on $\Bbb S^2$ except the north and south pole. Then I need to show that $I_{f(p)}(df_p(v)) \leq I_p(v)$ for all $p \in S= \Bbb S^2\setminus \{N,S\}  $ and $v\in T_pS$. Here $I$ is the first fundamental form.

I think that I got the continuity part. I showed it as follows: Explicitly, $f(x,y,z) = (\sqrt{1-z^2},0,z)$. For some point $p\in S$ there exists a local parametrization $\textbf{x} :U \to V\cap S$ such that $\textbf{x}(q)=p$ for some $q\in U$ where $U$ and $V$ are open subsets of $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R^3$ respectively. Then define $\textbf{y}:U\to W \cap C$ via $\textbf{y} = f(\textbf{x})$ for some open set $W \subset \Bbb R^3$. Then we define $f$ to be differentiable at a point $p\in S$ if $\textbf{y}$ is differentiable at $\textbf{x}^{-1}(p)$. Now we see that $f$ when seen as a function from $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R^3$ is a differentiable function expect at $z = \pm 1$. Therefore $\textbf{y}$ is differentiable due to the differentiability of $\textbf{x}$ and $f$ restricted to $S$. Computing the derivatives gives $\textbf{y}_u   = \nabla f \cdot  \textbf{x}_u  = \left(\frac{-z}{\sqrt{1-z^2}} ,0,1 \right)\cdot \textbf{x}_u $ and $\textbf{y}_v =\nabla f \cdot  \textbf{x}_v $.

The next part I do not fully understand though. I want to calculate $df_p(v)$. Now I think it should be $(df_p)_{ij} = \frac{\partial f_i }{\partial x_j}$ where $f = (f_1,f_2,f_3)$ and $(x_1,x_2,x_3) = (x,y,z)$. Then I get that

$$df_p = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 &0&0\\0 &0&0  \\ \frac{-z}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}&0&1  \end{matrix}  \right) .$$

However then $I_{f(p)}(df_p(v))  =\frac{z^2}{1-z^2}v_1^2 + v_3^2  $ which is not necessarily smaller than $v_1^2+v_2^2+v_3^2 = I_p(v)$. Here $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3) \in T_p S$. What am I doing wrong? I think my understanding of what exactly $df_{f(p)}(v)$ means is not really great and I might be making a mistake here. Thanks!

EDIT: I am very new to differential geometry so if my question seems to not make sense or things are very weird please feel free to let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your formula for $f$ should be $f(x,y,z) = (\sqrt{1-z^2},0,z)$. So you can try recomputing.

But I would prefer to work in spherical coordinates $(\phi,\theta)$, where (using the mathematician's notation, not the physicist's)
$$(x,y,z) = (\sin\phi\cos\theta,\sin\phi\sin\theta,\cos\phi).$$
Then $f(\phi,\theta) = (\phi,0)$. You can easily check that if $v = a \dfrac{\partial}{\partial\phi} + b\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$, then $I(v) = a^2 + b^2\sin^2\phi$. But it's easy to see that $df_{(\phi,\theta)}(v) = a \dfrac{\partial}{\partial\phi}$, and $I(df_p(v)) = a^2 \le a^2+b^2\sin^2\phi = I(v)$.

**EDIT**: If you insist on parametrizing the sphere as a graph, use $(y,z)$ as local coordinates. Then if $p=(\sqrt{1-y^2-z^2},y,z)$, $df_p$ will send $v=a \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} + b\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}$ to $b \dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}$. I leave it to you to check that $$I_p(v) = \frac{(1-z^2)a^2+2yzab+(1-y^2)b^2}{1-y^2-z^2},$$
which is in fact greater than or equal to
$$I_{f(p)}(df_p(v)) = \frac{b^2}{1-z^2}.$$
(Their difference is $\dfrac{(a+byz-az^2)^2}{(1-z^2)(1-y^2-z^2)}$!)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! I did indeed make a stupid mistake in the formula for $f$. However this was a copying mistake from my hand written work, so the differential is correct as far as I know. Is there any way to do it not in spherical coordinates? Thanks!

Comment: See edit, if you insist :)